# how to get category value from xml params?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have the following field in xml:

```
<field
   name="cat1"
   type="category"
   extension="COM_CONTENT"
   label="MOD_ITEM_CAT1"
   description="MOD_ITEM_CAT_DESC" />
```

Now, I wanted to get selected value:

```
echo $params->get('cat1');
```

Which shows me **8** (the value of selected option) not it's title.

I've category title `people` and it should show people instead of 8.

So, how to extract the title of the category?

Comment: Please post this as an answer and mark it as solved ;)

Comment: Is there no way to get it with category type?

Comment: Not via the form field. In you want to use the `type="category"` this this will always return an integer. You could write a small database query to get the name from the ID. I've tried testing with Joomla's `JCategories` class, but it appears to be protected. Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: However, I did it with type category too, but will post answer tomorrow if needed.

Answer (score 0):

However, I solved the problem by changing the type category to sql:

```
<field
   name="cat1"
   type="sql"
   query="SELECT title AS value, title FROM #__categories"
   label="MOD_ITEM_CAT1"
   description="MOD_ITEM_CAT_DESC" />
```

And this outputs category title people.

```
echo $params->get('cat1'); //outputs people
```